# Loading a table from a csv file: Error code 1292 Incorrect DATA value, but it's correct

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file with dates written as YYYY-MM-DD but I'm getting an incorrect date value while importing the file. I created the table and tried to import a csv file as it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE afiliados (
    afiliado_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha DATE,
    nombre VARCHAR(30),
    municipio VARCHAR(20),
    dni_impreso VARCHAR(2),
    ficha_bien_llenada VARCHAR(2),
    comentario VARCHAR(100)
);

DESCRIBE afiliados;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/fichis.csv' 
INTO TABLE afiliados 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

[And here is what the csv file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXPyl.png)

When I execute the second part, i get this:

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '' for column 'fecha' at row 1

I'm following this tutorial
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

I'm not sure if it's the correct to use ENCLOSED BY "" or LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' but the guy in the tutorial had a pretty similar file to mine. Either way, erasing these terms yields the same result.

EDIT: Managed to solve it by importing the file using a wizard that MySQL Workbench has, but I'm still wondering how to do it manually.

Comment: Is the first row in your .csv file contains the column names? If so, remove the row and try import again.